# loop over data frame column by names in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame, each column is a categorical variable, and a column called target with value 0 or 1.
I am trying to loop over a data frame by columns and calculate the mean target by different level of each column.

```
n = c(2, 2, 1) 
s = c(1, 0, 1) 
b = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE) 
target = c(1,0,0)
df = data.frame(n, s,b,target)

for(i in 1:a){
   aggregate(df$target ~ as.name(colnames(df)[1]), df,  mean)
}
```

It seems here I can't just replace n in

```
aggregate(df$target ~ n, df, mean)
```

with string. How to solve this kind of problems? Thanks very much.

Comment: You should be making a formula `aggregate(target ~ n, data = df, FUN = mean)`. You can construct a call using for example `sprintf`, e.g. `as.formula(sprintf("target ~ %s", colnames(df)[i]))`.

Comment: `lapply(df[,-4], function(x){aggregate(target ~ x, data = df, FUN = mean)})`?

Comment: Do you need multiple aggregate dfs or running/conditional averages? Please illustrate with desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much to Roman Luštrik's comment.

The code is,

```
for(i in 1:a){
col_formula <- as.formula(sprintf("target ~ %s", colnames(df)[i]))
aggregate(col_formula, data=df,  FUN=mean)
}
```

It gives the result I was looking for.